# ERROR Deployment laravel 9 project to vps

Tags: laravel, database

I need a lot of help, I'm trying to upload my Laravel 9 project to my server but I always get this error,

> **SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

I already configured the `.env` I already configured the database file in code, on my server I have everything configured correctly and I still get the same error, I tried with another project and it works but with this one I always get this error and I don't know why

Comment: Is this at least the correct user (and no password) as you set it up in your `.env` file?

Comment: No, it is another user that is configured, the problem is that it is taking the root user and that is not the user that I have configured

Comment: And you didn't think that was worth mentioning? Probably a cache thing, run `php artisan config:clear` to clear the cached config.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to upload it now, thanks

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the linked question. This is a cache issue, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message `... using password: NO` it seems you have not set `DB_PASSWORD` in `.env`. Also specify what database server you are using.

To verify your configuration is correct then run `php artisan tinker` in production server and type `config('database')` and see the results. If you want you can post them here **but replace password, host with xxx**.
If you do not have terminal access in production then create a route with clojure with `dd( config('database'))` and see the data for the appropriate database connection you are using. Keep in mind you have to **immediately remove this route** so you info are not exposed to the world.
Also, in case your database server is in another host then make sure database allows connections from other hosts.

Comment: I have to configure it, I created the route but the application does not recognize it, I don't understand why with this project I have this error

Comment: You can help me?

Comment: I share the error: https://flareapp.io/share/x5MEEEx5

Comment: It does not seem the env has loaded. Are you sure that `.env` exists next to `composer.json`? Also as other users suggested try clearing your cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server's terminal, run `php artisan optimize`.

If you don't, you can use `Artisan` facade. there's two way to clear out caches.

***Option 1 (using Artisan facade):***

You can call it at the beginning of the routes file or a controller method like this:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('config:clear');
```

The above command will clear the config's cache.

Also, for routes, you can use the below command:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('route:clear');
```

***Option 2 (delete cache files):***

Another way is to delete all files in `bootstrap/cache` folder.

Comment: I just did what you said but it's still the same

Comment: I share the error: https://flareapp.io/share/x5MEEEx5

Comment: add this `dd(Artisan::output());` after Artisan:call. There's a chance because of route caching, the `web.php` doesn't even load.

Comment: What command do I put in the path?

Comment: Try these commands at the beginning of a controller method. 
You don't see any changes at the first call, but after the next call, cache must be cleared out.

Comment: I added the FQN of the Artisan class.

Comment: @Dingakill I added another. You can clear cache files manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to upload it now, thanks